# Downloading Twitter Images using Python 2.7

Tags: python, twitter, urllib, beautifulsoup

I'm using this code to download twitter image from its url(line).

```
line = 'https://twitter.com/SidraAyaz/status/545821994172686336/photo/1'
resp = urllib.urlopen(line)
data = str(resp.readlines())
bs = BeautifulSoup(data)
imgUrl = bs.find('img', attrs={'alt': 'Embedded image permalink'}).get('src')
urllib.urlretrieve(imgUrl, "cloud1/"+str(n)+".png")
```

Problem occurs when the url points to an album(multiple images). Is there any way of finding out if the url points to an image or an image or an album? How do we download complete album from its url?

Comment: You need to find the files one by one and download

Comment: but that is not a practical solution since i need to download images from a large number of urls